# Outlook VBA Macro not modifying email

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am running the following script on the event that I receive an email from a specific address with a specific subject.  The goal is to tag an email with a hyperlink that will be useful for the recipient of said email to have in the original message's body.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Megatron(MyMail As MailItem)
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim strID As String
Dim strLink As String
Dim strNewText As String
Dim strLinkText As String

'On Error Resume Next
Set objOL = Application
strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set MyMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
If Not MyMail Is Nothing Then
    Set objNS = objOL.Session
    MyMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    If MyMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML Then
    MsgBox ("set to html")
    End If

    strLink = "http://www.example.com"
strLinkText = "Click on this Example!"
strNewText = "<p><a href=" & Chr(34) & strLink & _
         Chr(34) & ">" & strLinkText & "</a></p>"
MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "</body>", _
                      strNewText, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
    MyMail.Save     
    MsgBox ("Hyperlink appended!")
Else
MsgBox ("Failure!")
End If
End Sub
```

While I get the message box telling me that the proper event occurred it appears that no actual changes are made (or are not being saved properly?).

This is the first work I have done with any kind of programming. I've gone through some tutorials for VB specifically, but I am very new to this.  Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: what's objMail?  Did you set it earlier?  Same with objMsg?  I'd add MsgBox's throughout, echoing out things like objMsg.HTMLBody to make sure you're modifying what you think you're modifying, and not undefined objects.  Looks like you should be manipulating objItem throughout . . .

Comment: Comment out that `On Error Resume Next` - how are you going to debug with that there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case of needing to use `Option Explicit` to require explicit variable declarations. Use this, since you are learning VBA. Also avoid the habit of using `On Error Resume Next` as this ignores all error handling.

You might not realize this but you are referring to your mail item in the following ways:

- MyMail
- objItem
- objMsg
- objMail

Note that the following two commands

> objMsg.HTMLBody
>
> objMail.Save

are performed on non-existent objects.

Remove the above three extra references:

```
Sub Megatron(MyMail As MailItem)
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objItem As Object
Dim strID As String
Dim strLink As String
Dim strNewText As String
Dim strLinkText As String
strLink = "http://www.example.com"
strLinkText = "Click on this Example!"
strNewText = "<p><a href=" & Chr(34) & strLink & _
         Chr(34) & ">" & strLinkText & "</a></p>"
MyMail.HTMLBody = Replace(MyMail.HTMLBody, "</body>", _
                      strNewText, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
MyMail.Save
end Sub
```

You also don't need the cleanup either.

Comment: edit above reflects your suggestions (concurrent with above comments). I tried strictly your snippet here and still no hyperlink added to the emails.  Subsequently tried to manually set the MyMail.BodyFormat property (see edit) and it returns the same result.

Comment: @worseone are you sure this is actually being called? I am able to run the above to append your hyperlink to a mailitem. Are your emails not HTML to begin with?

Comment: I've tried testing if it is HTML already by setting if statements to inform me of the type, by manually setting it to HTML (as my edited code shows), and by throwing images into emails I am testing with.  Everything so far tells me that they are in HTML format.

Comment: Apparently the content type of the emails was multipart/alternative or similar, despite my attempts at conversion.  Forced an email out that was HTML and the solution worked.  Thanks for the help!